# Capturing or importing the To, From, Subject, and email body from an Outlook 2016 email item using C#

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I have been trying to build a program where I can capture/import/extract/retrieve information from fields in an open Outlook email item. I need to retrieve the To, From, Subject and email body. I am using Outlook 2016.

I have been able to pull in all emails from the INBOX folder. However, I have not been able to isolate 
it to retrieve information in the aforementioned fields from just a singular, open Outlook email item. Can somebody point me to a tutorial or code where only the open email's data has been retrieved? Code examples would be very helpful.

I attached a picture for more details.[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the currently selected message, use `Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection` collection.

Comment: Dmitry Streblechenko, Thanks so much I was able to do it using your recommendation.